# Google sheet javascript API - change background color to white

Tags: javascript, google-sheets-api

I have changed the google sheet row background color to red via javascript API.
I need to again change the background color to white.

My code is below RGB code I have used for white 255,255,255 it's not working.

```js
const request = {
  spreadsheetId, // fill with your own
  resource: {
    "requests": [
      {
        "repeatCell": {
          "range": {
            "sheetId": 0,
            "startRowIndex": 1,
            "endRowIndex": 2
          },
          // "fields": "userEnteredFormat"
          "cell": {
            "userEnteredFormat": {
              "backgroundColor": {
                'red': 255,
                'green': 255,
                'blue': 255
              },
            }
          },
          "fields": "userEnteredFormat(backgroundColor)"
        }
      },
      {
        "updateSheetProperties": {
          "properties": {
            "sheetId": 0,
            "gridProperties": {
              "frozenRowCount": 1
            }
          },
          "fields": "gridProperties.frozenRowCount"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
};

const resultData = await sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate(request);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your script, how about the following modification? In this modification, the property of `repeatCell` is modified as follows.

The property of `backgroundColor` is deprecated. Please be careful about this.

#### From:

```
{
  "repeatCell": {
    "range": {
      "sheetId": 0,
      "startRowIndex": 1,
      "endRowIndex": 2
    },
    "cell": {
      "userEnteredFormat": {
        "backgroundColor": {
          "red": 255,
          "green": 255,
          "blue": 255
        },
      }
    },
    "fields": "userEnteredFormat(backgroundColor)"
  }
}
```

#### To:

```
{
  "repeatCell": {
    "range": {
      "sheetId": 0,
      "startRowIndex": 1,
      "endRowIndex": 2
    },
    "fields": "userEnteredFormat(backgroundColorStyle)"
  }
}
```

or, if you want to set the white, you can also the following modification. Please set the values of `red`, `green` and `blue` like 0 to 1.

```
{
  "repeatCell": {
    "range": {
      "sheetId": 0,
      "startRowIndex": 1,
      "endRowIndex": 2
    },
    "cell": {
      "userEnteredFormat": {
        "backgroundColorStyle": {
          "rgbColor": {
            "red": 1,
            "green": 1,
            "blue": 1
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "fields": "userEnteredFormat(backgroundColorStyle)"
  }
}
```

- By this, `userEnteredFormat(backgroundColor)` is reset and the background color is set as white.

#### Reference:

- [CellFormat](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/cells#CellFormat)